# Why window.jQuery & window.$ is not set when I use node's require('jquery') and browserify

Tags: jquery, browserify

I have a piece of code as part of Karma test:

```
require('jquery');
require('jquery-ui');
require('./../jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js');
```

Before running tests, I run browserify:

```
browserify test\main.Spec.js -o test\main.Spec.run.js
```

Now when I run tests, I get the following error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery

However, when I manually assign `window.jQuery` everything is fine:

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery');
```

Why does `require('jquery')` not set `window.jQuery` and `window.$` and I have to do it on my own?

Answer (score 1):

The line `require('jquery');` (and others), work like requires in node, I'm guessing you're familiar to the concept. It returns the object, which you have to setup yourself.

If you wish to have `$` set as jquery, you'll have to set it **on your own**. Change the line to

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

Or if it absolutely has to be global, change it to `window.$`.